# How to Replace Plot Slot Numbers With Variable Names

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, curated-data, astronomy

The format of my data looks like:

```
{"Name", "HDNumber", "SpectralClass", "BVColorIndex", \
"EffectiveTemperature", "Mass", "Luminosity", "AbsoluteMagnitude", \
"ApparentMagnitude", "RightAscension", "Declination", \
"ConstellationName"}
```

I import and join classes of formatted AstronomicalData like:

```
importClassBStar1 = Import["tableClassBStar1.tsv", {"Data", {All}}, "HeaderLines" -> 1];
importClassBStar2 = Import["tableClassBStar2.tsv", {"Data", {All}}, "HeaderLines" -> 1];
importClassBStar3 = Import["tableClassBStar3.tsv", {"Data", {All}}, "HeaderLines" -> 1];
importClassBStar4 = Import["tableClassBStar4.tsv", {"Data", {All}}, "HeaderLines" -> 1];

importClassBStar = Join[importClassBStar1, importClassBStar2, importClassBStar3, importClassBStar4];
```

I then use Manipulate to vary the plot type and the targeted class of AstronomicalData:

```
Manipulate[
plotType[Tooltip[{#6, #7}, {#3, #6, #7}] & @@@ category,
PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large,
AxesLabel -> {"Mass", "Luminosity"}, PlotStyle -> Red,
PlotLabel -> "Mass vs Luminosity"],
{{plotType, ListLogLogPlot }, {ListPlot, ListLogPlot, ListLogLogPlot}},
{{category, importSubgiant }, {
importClassAStar -> "ClassA",
importClassBStar -> "ClassB",
importClassMStar -> "ClassM",
importClassOStar -> "ClassO",
importSubgiant -> "Subgiant",
importSupergiant -> "Supergiant",
importVariableStar -> "VariableStar",
unionGiants -> "UnionGiants",
unionAll -> "UnionAll"
}}]

ListPicker[Dynamic[a],
{
importClassAStar -> "ClassA",
importClassBStar -> "ClassB",
importClassMStar -> "ClassM",
importClassOStar -> "ClassO",
importSubgiant -> "Subgiant",
importSupergiant -> "Supergiant",
importVariableStar -> "VariableStar",
unionGiants -> "UnionGiants",
unionAll -> "UnionAll"
}
] ;
```

What I would like to do is replace the static slot numbers:

```
plotType[Tooltip[{#6, #7}, {#3, #6, #7}]
```

with something like:

```
plotType[Tooltip[{column1, column2}, {#3, column1, column2}],
{{column1, #6}, {#4, #5, #6, #7, #8}}, 
{{column2, #7}, {#4, #5, #6, #7, #8}},
```

Any ideas would be welcomed.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) and [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html)?

Comment: I edited your answer to improve the formatting.  It doesn't look syntactically complete - I apologise if I have introduced any errors.

Comment: If I replaceTooltip[{#6, #7}, {#3, #6, #7}] withTooltip[{Slot[6], Slot[7]}, {Slot[3], Slot[6], Slot[7]}] that works. But when I replace it withTooltip[{Slot[column1], Slot[column2]}, {Slot[3], Slot[column1], 
  Slot[column2]}] it fails. Where column1 and column indexes are defined as {{column1, 6}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}, {{column2, 7}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}

Answer (score 1):

Joseph,

You have to use the function [With](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html)

So your line should be as follows

```
With[{c1=column1},Tooltip[{c1, #7}, {#3, #6, #7}] &] @@@ category,
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked zKarp. Thank you! Still have to associate text to the selected numerical values but looks really good so far:

```
Manipulate[
 plotType[
  With[{c1 = column1, c2 = column2},
    Tooltip[{Slot[c1], Slot[c2]}, {Slot[3], Slot[c1], Slot[c2]}] &] @@@ 
   category,
  PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large,
  AxesLabel -> {"BVColorIndex", "AbsoluteMagnitude"}, PlotStyle -> Red,
  PlotLabel -> "AbsoluteMagnitude vs BVColorIndex"],
 {{column1, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}, {{column2, 8}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8}},
 {{plotType, ListLogLogPlot }, {ListPlot, ListLogPlot, 
   ListLogLogPlot}},
 {{category, importSubgiant }, {
   importClassAStar -> "ClassA",
   importClassBStar -> "ClassB",
   importClassMStar -> "ClassM",
   importClassOStar -> "ClassO",
   importSubgiant -> "Subgiant",
   importSupergiant -> "Supergiant",
   importVariableStar -> "VariableStar",
   unionGiants -> "UnionGiants",
   unionAll -> "UnionAll"
   }}]
ListPicker[Dynamic[a],
  {
   importClassAStar -> "ClassA",
   importClassBStar -> "ClassB",
   importClassMStar -> "ClassM",
   importClassOStar -> "ClassO",
   importSubgiant -> "Subgiant",
   importSupergiant -> "Supergiant",
   importVariableStar -> "VariableStar",
   unionGiants -> "UnionGiants",
   unionAll -> "UnionAll"
   }
  ] ;

(* 
4=BVColorIndex,
5=Temperature,
6=Mass,
7=Luminosity,8=AbsoluteMagnitude *)
```